# Vim Intended Folding - E490: No fold found

Tags: vim, folding

The first line in the file where I want to activate folding looks like:

```
# vim: fdm=indent fdn=1 sw=2 nobackup nowritebackup noswapfile bufhidden=wipe foldclose=all
```

After that I'm trying to create a fold:

```
Foobar
    Bar
    Bar
    Bar
```

When I save the file and press `z+c` there is the message `E490: No fold found`.

My `.vimrc` looks like:

```
colorscheme desert
syntax on

set nu
set listchars=tab:\|-
set tabstop=4
set noexpandtab
set spell
set spelllang=de,en
set cryptmethod=blowfish2
set foldenable

:map <F2> <C-z>
hi SpellBad ctermbg=darkgrey
```

Comment: What does `set syntax` say? Also you could try once with your plugins disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You could first select all the lines in the file which you want to be folded using visual mode (press v then use j/k to select all the lines which you need to be folded), now press zf (with the text selected) to create a fold.

You can then use za to toggle the fold.

You can find more help regarding all the fold commands inside of vim only.
Type :help folding to open the in built vim documentation on the topic of folding.

At the time of my typing this question was asked 7 years ago. So the original poster might have already found this answer. So, I'm posting for those who would stumble upon this question and are in need of a quick fix.

Comment: I don't think that's what OP asked for. You describe manual folding while OP has `fdm=indent` in their modeline. This is about a very specific error and not "how do I create a fold?".

Comment: I answered why on pressing `z+c` he's getting no fold found. One way which I thought could solve this was by creating a fold, that's why I suggested him this.